# Firebase rule resolving wrong

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to set firebase rules to my database but i'm having problem with `data` and `newData`

According to firebase:

> newData A RuleDataSnapshot corresponding to the data that will result
>   if the write is allowed.
>
> For .write and .validate rules, the newData variable gives you a
>   RuleDataSnapshot corresponding to the data that will result if the
>   write is allowed (it is a "merging" of the existing data plus the new
>   data being written).

So I have the following rule:

```
"users_details":{  
                "$uid":{
                   ".write":"$uid == auth.uid && newData.exists()",
                   ".read":"$uid == auth.uid",
                    ".validate":"newData.child('auth').hasChild('crsfToken')",
                }
```

User has a field `auth` which has a field `crsfToken`... so everytime someone writes a user i want to ensure the "edited" user will have `auth/crsfToken`

Ok.

Let's say a have an actual valid user `abc`.

Then i want to set another field on `abc`, that has no relation to any rule...
lets say: `abc.field.subField = 1`

so what I am doing is: 
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Firebase.NODE_USERS_DETAILS).child(user.getUserid()).child("field").child("subField").setValue(1);`

this isn't changing `auth` nor `crsfToken` but i'm getting `Permision Denied`

When I do a simulation on console, i see that isn't writing because the validate rule is denied

why? is there any way to debug firebase rules and see what is `newData` on a simulation?

Comment: Does `users_details/$uid/auth` have a value for `crsfToken`? If not, that would explain the error.

Answer (score 0):

Rules are resolving ok :) Because rules will be checked for all data manipulations on user_details/UID/*. So if you update user_detail/UID/field/subField, your rules will be checked and you will get access denied as you are. You said that you want to check for newData.auth.crsfToken and you are doing that indeed, but now you want to update field/subField without checking that? In which case you don't want to check crsfToken existence?